# radar-chart has distorted look

Tags: r, radar-chart, distortion, spider-chart

My radarchart colored lines look distorted. If you look at dark blue line on the left - it is not smooth but has a zigzag pattern. How to improve it?

| Herbizide | Diesel | Energieverbrauch | THG.Emissionen | Bodenabtrag | Regenwürmer_Abnahme | Insekte_abnahme | Tox_Aqua | Tox_terr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0.68 | 0.68 | 0.69 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0.44 | 0.54 | 0.68 | 0.81 | 0.69 | 1 | 0 | 0.42 | 0.42 |
| 1 | 0.14 | 0.7 | 0.4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

```
dput(head(umw_ris))
 structure(list(Herbizide = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0.44, 1), Diesel = c(1, 
0, 1, 0.68, 0.54, 0.14), Energieverbrauch = c(1, 0, 1, 0.68, 
0.81, 0.7), THG.Emissionen = c(1, 0, 1, 0.69, 0.69, 0.4), Bodenabtrag = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1), Regenwürmer_Abnahme = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Insekte_Abnahme = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Tox_Aqua = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0.42, 1), Tox_Terr = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0.42, 1)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3MH_2HH", "1HA_2MH_1HH", 
"3BS_2MH", "3S"), class = "data.frame")
library(fmsb)
library(scales)
umw_ris<- rbind(rep(1,8) , rep(0,8) , umw_old)
coul2<-c("blue2", "steelblue2","springgreen4","springgreen2")
radarchart(umw_ris, axistype=1, 
          #custom polygon
          pcol=coul2, plwd=4 , plty=1,
          #custom the grid
          cglcol="grey", cglty=3, axislabcol="gray20", 
          caxislabels=seq(0,1,5), 
                     calcex=0.8,cglwd=0.4,vlcex=1)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Provide example data as `dput(head(mydata))`

Comment: ... and in what way do you feel it is distorted?  It looks fine to me.

Comment: structure(list(Herbizide = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0.44, 1), Diesel = c(1, 
0, 1, 0.68, 0.54, 0.14), Energieverbrauch = c(1, 0, 1, 0.68, 
0.81, 0.7), THG.Emissionen = c(1, 0, 1, 0.69, 0.69, 0.4), Bodenabtrag = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1), Regenwürmer_Abnahme = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Insekte_Abnahme = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Tox_Aqua = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0.42, 1), Tox_Terr = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0.42, 1)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3MH_2HH", "1HA_2MH_1HH", 
"3BS_2MH", "3S"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: The blue line is a zigzag line not a smooth one.

Comment: that might be an artifact, try increasing the DPI or the resolution of the picture.